# How to make child element higher z-index than parent?

Tags: css, z-index

Suppose I have this code:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Hello world
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wholePage"></div>
```

This jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZjXMR/

Now, I need to have`<div class="child">` in above of `<div class="wholePage">` but in the jsFiddle you can see that the child element rendered before `<div class="wholePage">`.

If you remove the `parent` class `position` or `z-index`, everything works fine. This is the correct behavior that I need: http://jsfiddle.net/ZjXMR/1/

How can I do that with `z-index` and without removing anything from page?

Comment: closely related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333

Answer (score 107, accepted):

This is impossible as a child's `z-index` is set to the same stacking index as its parent.

You have already solved the problem by removing the z-index from the parent, keep it like this or make the element a sibling instead of a child.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, but as I mentioned before, I have to solve the problem without removing anything.

Comment: `z-index` isn't inherited.

Comment: @boltclock It is taken from the parent: http://jsfiddle.net/ykzEH/

Comment: That's not inheritance. The `z-index: 50` appears over `z-index: 100` because the 1 and 50 are in the base stacking context, whereas 100 is in the stacking context of 1. Since 50 is greater than 1, 50 appears above 1 and everything in 1's context, but the 100 still retains a `z-index` of 100 *within 1*.

Comment: Ok, here it is with 1, 2 and 3. http://jsfiddle.net/ykzEH/1/ I've always understood that the parent element sets the z-index of all its children (I knew it wasn't inherited though.. Dunno why I wrote that :D)

Comment: @Kyle : If you don't know why you wrote that is not correct then edit the answer to be correct.

Comment: just to note that if there are other css styles at play, then you'll want to unset the z-index of those rules, you can test that by using the * { z-index: unset; } if that works, you'll know you are on the right track. Always be aware of external forces at play, its easy to have this happen on more complicated pages where there are 2 or more developers at any given time, etc.  Obviously rewriting/reparenting is desirable but if you dont have access to the source (is not your department or is read-only for some other reason) you are gonna be up against a wall, forcing zindexes can help or hurt!

Answer (score 26):

Nothing is impossible. Use the force.

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: If we can't change the style of parent so this is a perfect solution to resolve problem. I tried and nice . thanks

Comment: > If you remove the parent class position or z-index, everything works fine.
You've just removed the parent z-index, which I believe the OP couldn't modify.

Comment: position:relative changed the stacking order of parent. I think it is probably because relative make 'parent' step out of the current page structure. Check out this:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: Alternatively, set parent z-index to `auto`.

Answer (score 11):

To achieve what you want without removing any styles you have to make the z-index of the '.parent' class bigger then the '.wholePage' class.

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4; /*matters since it's sibling to wholePage*/
}

.child {
    position: relative;
    z-index:1; /*doesn't matter */
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZjXMR/2/

Answer (score 8):

Give the parent z-index: -1, or opacity: 0.99

Comment: If people are wondering what the opacity:0.99 is all about I suggest you read this link. http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: This seems not to work in IE 11

Comment: EVERYBODY ON THIS PAGE SHOULD READ THE ARTICLE LINKED IN THE PREVIOUS COMMENT! Seriously, everything you need to know about z-index - very helpful stuff, with some real silver bullets sprinkled in the mix too.

Comment: This solved the problem for me when I had 3 parents divs and 3 child divs in each parent. So, all 9 divs are stacked together. But, made translateZ problematic on children.

Comment: CSS has now a dedicated property just for creating a new stacking context: `isolation` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/isolation).

Answer (score 5):

Use non-static position along with greater z-index in child element:

```
.parent {
    position: absolute
    z-index: 100;
}

.child {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 101;
}
```

Comment: To elaborate a little on the "Use non-static position", the default behavior for elements that have no position property specified will default to "static." [Reading about Static](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position-3/#valdef-position-static). This lacks functionality around things like the left, right, bottom and top until given a position, the same applies for z-index.

Answer (score 5):

Try using this code, it worked for me:

```
z-index: unset;
```