# z-index - getting deep nested element to the front

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I have the below HTML & CSS, I want take out the little black square to the front i.e. over & above the overlay, I should only see the black square.
This markup is just the stripped version of my code.

> Black box on the top right need to get in front of all layers, including
>   overlay layer.

Plunk - http://plnkr.co/edit/FEo8AQBBrh1YMHrduZeM?p=preview

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="div1">div1
      <div class="div1-1">div1-1
        <div class="div1-1-1">
          div 1-1-1
          <div class="div1-1-1-1">
            1-1-1-1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
body{color:#fff;}
.overlay{position:fixed; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; background:#000;opacity:.5; z-index:1005;}
.div1{width:100%; height:600px; background:red; position:relative;}
.div1-1 {width:auto; height:600px; background:blue; position:absolute; z-index:2; left:40px;
  top:0; bottom:0; right:0;
}
.div1-1-1 {width:100%; height:40px; background:green; position:absolute; z-index:15;
  top:0;right:0; left:0;
}
.div1-1-1-1 {width:40px; height:40px; background:black; position:absolute; right:0; top:0;}
```

Comment: which black square..not clear. if not mistaking its already up

Comment: @Pilot The black square in the top right.

Comment: @Pilot - I just moved it to little left, as button from plunker were overlapping a bit. Please check now.

Comment: @whyAto8 You should name your divs better

Comment: @BradlySpicer - Apologies if its confusing, but I just wanted to show the parent-child kind of relation

Comment: @whyAto8 You should use z-index value for `div1-1-1-1` more than `overlay` div `z-index`. And using `z-index` value in range of 1k is bad

Comment: @Pilot - Well, as I said, its a stripped version of my code where there are other z-index values in play as well. Anyway, giving div1-1-1-1 more than overlay doesnt work.

Comment: @whyAto8 - Were you able to figure out a solution to this without changing the structure and without changing the z-index of the parent elements?

Answer (score 1):

I have changed a lot of structure, for achieving the task, please check the [Code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GaQda4i5xsJAmWwTb6ux?p=preview)

> CSS Code:
>   /* Styles go here */

```
body{color:#fff;}
.overlay {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 20;
}
.div1{width:100%; height:600px; background:red; position:relative;}
.div1-1 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0000FF;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 600px;
    left: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: auto;
}

.div1-1-1 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #008000;
    height: 40px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.div1-1-1-1 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

> HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="div1">div1
      <div class="div1-1">div1-1
        <div class="div1-1-1">
          div 1-1-1
          <div class="div1-1-1-1">
            1-1-1-1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="overlay"></div>-->
  </body>

</html>
```

Please add comments if you have any other issue.

Regards D.

Comment: I see that you have removed z-index for 2 parents, but I cant do that, since I have a full fledge app running, so cant alter this.

Comment: Oh okay, I will try to find an alternate solution without removing z-index.

Answer (score 0):

It seems z-index is always inherited from parent, more details in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057361/how-to-make-child-element-upper-than-parent-with-z-index).

One way is to remove the z-index of parent divs and add only to the required div. [Plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OuKFSBlNaY9wWGY4ziQv?p=preview)

Another is to have it has a sibling instead of child. And update the z-index accordingly.

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/82NDDjlzgfxfaoJKvZQM?p=preview)

```
<div class="div1">div1
  <div class="div1-1">div1-1
    <div class="div1-1-1">
      div 1-1-1

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div1-1-1-1">
        1-1-1-1
      </div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

CSS Change

```
.div1-1-1-1 {width:40px; height:40px; background:black; position:absolute; right:100px; top:0;z-index:1010;}
```

Comment: structure is disturbed..please check it again.

Comment: @Baga - I cant neither remove parent z-index nor place it as sibling.

Comment: @whyAto8 Oh interesting.have voted up your question..hope someone would come up with the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Baga, lets hope there is a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I am sending another solution, which only alters the structure, and that does not remove the z-indexes of any elements.

[JS Fiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/thcv3/)

> HTML Code:

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="div1">div1
    <div class="div1-1">div1-1
        <div class="div1-1-1">div 1-1-1
            <!--<div class="div1-1-1-1">1-1-1-1</div>-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div1-1-1-1">1-1-1-1</div>
</div>
```

> CSS Code:

```
body {
    color:#fff;
}
.overlay {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:#000;
    opacity:.5;
    z-index:1005;
}
.div1 {
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
}
.div1-1 {
    width:auto;
    height:600px;
    background:blue;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    left:40px;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
.div1-1-1 {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background:green;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:15;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
}
.div1-1-1-1 {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background:black;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

> **Notable Points:**

1. You have to add the division `<div class="div1-1-1-1">1-1-1-1</div>`
   as a child of `<div class="div1">` instead of  `<div
   class="div1-1-1"></div>`
2. Class `.div1-1-1-1` should be given equal or higher z-index than `.overlay` class.

You can do this by simply changing the layout structure by HTML, or by jQuery.

If you have any other query then please add comment below.

Regards D.

Comment: thanks for that, but unfortunately, i cant alter the html structure either. :-(

Comment: Awesome, then you will need to mention all the points in that are to be considered, like "structure cannot be changed" and "z-index cannot be removed from the parents or any div"