# Make child div in back of parent div with z-index?

Tags: html, css

No matter what I try, the child div is always in front of the parent. Is there a way to make the child div in back of the parent? z-index doesn't seem to work.

Notes :

1. I don't want to change the html
2. parent must have a z-index
3. duplicate "How to make child element upper than parent with z-index" doesn't make grammatical sense and is hard to read, and didn't really help me.

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div id='child'>
    </div>
</div>

#parent {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;  
    z-index:100;
}

#child {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    position:absolute;  
    z-index:-100;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/j6e9qho3/)

Comment: Remove the z-index on the parent. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/j6e9qho3/2/

Comment: within the context of my program, the parent must have a z-index

Comment: `z-index` will not work for this since child elements inherit the `z-index` of their parent, after that they apply their own `zindex`. So z-index in this case will let all the child elements compete however will not allow them to leave their parent element. Here is what I mean : http://jsfiddle.net/nvLyacje/1/
If you could give more context to your constraints maybe we could find a work around

Comment: Also, duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057361/how-to-make-child-element-upper-than-parent-with-z-index

Comment: what's your specify problem it is? I think your model about **z-index** is not match the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the `child` `div` actually contained in the `parent`.  Since the positions are absolute you can do this:

```
<div id='parent'>
</div>
<div id='child'>
</div>
```

Now if the `z-index` of `parent` is less than that of `child` it will appear on top.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve that because they are part of the same [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). However a workaround could be set `opacity: 0` to child

```css
#parent {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <div id='child'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's not possible to position a parent on top of a child. Without changing the HTML you can however use`:before` or `:after` to create a new element and position *that* on top of the child;

```
#parent:after {
    background: red;
    content: "ON TOP";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j6e9qho3/12/

Edit: Or seeing as the effect of the parent being on top of the child is that the child isn't visible at all, the easiest thing to do is probably `#child {display: none}`. But I assume that doesn't work for you for other reasons.

Perhaps if you explained what you want to accomplish we could be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I wanted by dealing with siblings inside the parent...

```
<div id='parent'>

    <div id='child1'>
    </div>

    <div id='child2'>
    </div>
</div>
```

where parent is a transparent container with its own z-index, but the children are the actual color squares that are drawn (each with their own z-index).