# Using CSS and z-index, how can you place an element that is a child of a child behind the top parent?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, z-index

I am currently building a menu that will be used as a top nav in our portal environment. Unfortunately, due to the nature of business controls, and the lack of flexibility with modifying enterprise code - we are limited to making this work with CSS.

The problem I have is, the menu that /flies out/ from the dropdown menu, appears in front of the parent element. The behavior I want to have, is that when you hover over an item that has a flyout menu - it will slide out like a drawer - from [behind] the parent.

Now this is somewhat similar to a suckerfish menu structure:

```
<ul>
   <li>My Item
      <ul>
         <li>drop 1</li>
         <li>drop 2</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>My other Item
      <ul>
         <li>Sub1</li>
         <li>Sub2
            <ul>
               <li>Flyout1</li>
               <li>Flyout2</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

When you expand the 'Flyout1/Flyout2' menu, it appears in front of the Sub1/Sub2 menu.

Here is a working example at codepen:

https://codepen.io/barrychapman/pen/YMYoRd

I have tried all the tricks, setting opacities to .99, -1 z-index, etc.

Comment: This gives you an answer i guess, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057361/how-to-make-child-element-upper-than-parent-with-z-index

Comment: @JoykalInfotech _“firstly z-index doesn't go lower than -1”_ - not true …

Comment: Sorry but I don't find any articles related to lower than that, and also personally working, no negative lower than -1 had worked for me. Please enlighten me! @04FS

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/integer

Comment: Thanks for this !! Earlier nothing had worked for me. maybe i was putting it in wrong way. I take my comment back.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333

Comment: This is for a child two down