# Using z-index to move a foreground element before a grid in the background

Tags: html, css, z-index

In the following example I create a simple grid using the class `row` and `cell` and would like to render the element with class `task` spanning over two grid cells. I use `z-index: 2` style to bring the task to the top but this does not seem to work as expected and i still see the vertical grid between two cells. What is my mistake?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <style>
    .row {
      height: 34px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    .cell {
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
      width: 60px;
      min-width: 60px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .last-cell {
      border-right-width: 1px;
    }
    .task {
      background-color: #3db9d3;
      height: 30px;
      width: 119px;
      margin: 1px 0 0 1px;
      z-index: 2;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="task">Task</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell last-cell"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Works as it should. Your mistake is misunderstanding of the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54903621/8620333

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to establish a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) by removing the z-index on the parent element. Also, the z-index only applies to positioned elements so you need to set `position: relative` on the Task div:

```css
.row {
  height: 34px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.cell {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
  width: 60px;
  min-width: 60px;
}

.last-cell {
  border-right-width: 1px;
}

.task {
  background-color: #3db9d3;
  height: 30px;
  width: 119px;
  margin: 1px 0 0 1px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="task">Task</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell last-cell"></div>
</div>
```

See also [How to make child element higher z-index than parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057361/how-to-make-child-element-higher-z-index-than-parent)