# CSS: Getting text to appear above the gradient in my div

Tags: html, css, background, z-index, gradient

I'm working on a news aggregation site's homepage and we're supposed to have a couple of areas that pull in content with the photo in the background and text on top with a gradient between the two. For the most part I have it except even though the z-index is lower, the gradient still appears above the text box. I've already experimented with this on a solid background just to be sure. The code and example are here: http://jsfiddle.net/cx0uvshd/

```
<style type="text/css">
    .feature {
        position: relative;
        float: left; 
        width: 465px; 
        height: 170px;  
        margin-top: 24px; 
        margin-right: 30px; 
    }
    .feature.last { 
        margin-right: 0; 
    }
    .feature-bottom {
        background: none;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0 30px 6px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 200;
        line-height: 1;
    }
    .feature-bottom::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 100;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=0 );
    }
    .feature-bottom h3 { 
        color: #FFF; 
        font-size: 15px; 
        font-weight: 400; 
        margin: 0; 
    }
    .feature-bottom h2 { 
        color: #FFF; 
        font-size: 24px; 
        font-weight: 400; 
        margin: 0; 
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add (position:relative) and (z-index:201) to your feature-bottoms h3 and h2. Find revised code below:

```
.feature { position: relative; float: left; width: 465px; height: 170px;  margin-top: 24px; margin-right: 30px; }
.feature.last { margin-right: 0; }
.feature-bottom {
    background: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 30px 6px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 200;
    line-height: 1;
}
.feature-bottom::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=0 );
}
.feature-bottom h3 { position:relative; z-index:201; color: #FFF; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 400; margin: 0; }
.feature-bottom h2 { position:relative; z-index:201; color: #FFF; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 400; margin: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not applying gradient to `.feature-bottom`? Like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/cx0uvshd/2/

In the current version you have the `:before` element overlaying despite bigger `z-index`. You need [new stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

[Here's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032856/z-index-of-before-or-after-to-be-below-the-element-is-that-possible)

Answer (score 0):

A not so clean solution is to add another div with the content below the gradient one. Then give that div a class that is a copy of feature-bottom. Then set color of feature-bottom to transparent to hide the text. Also change the last two selectors to use the copy class. Also duplicate the last two selectors to use for the new class. [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o9fsq2km/1/)

CSS:

```
    .feature { position: relative; float: left; width: 465px; height: 170px; margin-top: 24px; margin-right: 30px; }
    .feature.last { margin-right: 0; }
```

```
/*Copy of feature bottom*/
.feature-bottom2 {
background: none;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
padding: 0 30px 6px;
width: 100%;
z-index: 200;
line-height: 1;
}
.feature-bottom {
    color: transparent;
background: none;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
padding: 0 30px 6px;
width: 100%;
z-index: 200;
line-height: 1;
}
.feature-bottom::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 100;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000',  GradientType=0 );
}
/* Copy of below*/
.feature-bottom2 h3 { color: #FFF; font-size: 15px; font-    weight: 400; margin: 0; }
.feature-bottom2 h2 { color: #FFF; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 400; margin: 0; }

.feature-bottom h3 { font-size: 15px; font-weight: 400; margin: 0; }
.feature-bottom h2 { font-size: 24px; font-weight: 400; margin: 0; }
```