# Html Text inside <div> is not showing up

Tags: html, css

I have tried to create a card which rotates in 3D if mouse pointer hovers over it. I have successfully added the background and image of the front of the card, but **when trying to add text to it (ie, when trying to add text to a div element), it is not displayed.**

Erroneous html code:

```
    <div class="front">
        <div class="front_card_icon">
            <img src="image/indoor_plants_icon_white.svg">
        </div>

        <p>THIS TEXT IS THE PROBLEM</p>
    </div>
```

Erroneous css code:

```
.front {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    transition: transform .6s linear;
    background-color: #2D3436;
}

.front_card_icon{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 8%;
    transform: scale(0.70);
    z-index: 2;
}

.front p {
  positon:relative;
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
}
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021149/text-in-the-div-not-showing) post, the problem should have been solved after using `position:relative` on the

tag, but that sadly didn't resolve my problem.

This is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/King_Fish/s4h0u96j/) for my problem. Note that there the text is properly displayed, because the image can't be loaded. However, when the image is loaded, **the text is not displayed, ALTHOUGH the image is transparent**.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: make the z-index of the text bigger than the image. Actually the image is on the top

Comment: Side note, typo in `.front p {
  positon:`

Comment: What if set `position: absolute` to `.front_card_icon` ?

Comment: Use this site [https://placeholder.pics/] with the dimension of the image you are using, so we can debug the issue better. I did a quick test and it is likely fixed with z-index as @TemaniAfif suggested, and position:absolute on the `p` and `.front_card_icon` as @fiter suggested. Alternatively you can use an svg as a background image.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ht2eb7xj/1/ this is what you are looking for?

Comment: After adding top padding to the text to push it down, the code worked! Here is the updated jsfiddle with the desired effect: https://jsfiddle.net/King_Fish/4c8uL1p6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="front">
    <div class="front_card_icon">
        <img src="image/indoor_plants_icon_white.svg">
    </div>

    <p>Text to be centered vertically on top of image</p>
</div>
```

Your p tag is below the image and so the text is being pushed down and hidden by it's parent container.

To center the text within it's parent **div** (minimally) you would have to:

1. break the **p** tag out of the normal flow using `position: absolute` (which will help position it correctly - but will also cause it to disappear behind the image)
2. bring the **p** tag back on top with `z-index: 2`
3. and centre the **p** tag vertically with:

```
   position:absolute;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anandamasri/8no9up5g/1/)

A more elegant solution might involve switching stategy and applying the image as a background. That would take the **img** tag out of the content flow, allowing the text to be centred without absolute positioning and z-indexing.

Answer (score 1):

You should set your `p` element's position to fixed and then give it `50%` of `top` and `left` :

```
.front p {
  position:fixed;
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  z-index:3;
}
```

Here is the live result([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m89njr1t/)).
For more information please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container).