# Position :after below the div

Tags: css

I am trying to apply the solution found in the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032856/z-index-of-before-or-after-to-be-below-the-element-is-that-possible), but it is not working in my case.

I want to bring the red circle above the green line.

```css
.box{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
.dot{
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.dot:after{
  background: green;
  content: '';
  height: 100px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: add a z-index to `.dot` and make sure it's greater than what `.dot:after` has

Comment: @slash197 The problem with that approach is that the `.dot:after` is a child of `.dot`.  It therefore will never have a lower `z-index` than its parent.  `z-index` uses the closest relative parent for reference on its stacking order.  That's also why in a document you can have a `<main>` section with z indexes through to the thousands and still have the site `<header>` stack higher than them (provided `<main>` has a lower index than `<header>` for instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just make the red dot be an `:after` rather than the element styles itself?

```css
.box{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
.dot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.dot:after{
  background: red;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.dot:before{
  background: green;
  content: '';
  height: 100px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
```