# CSS before / after - stacking order. Why both are on top?

Tags: html, css

I wish that in CSS the before will render before the container, and the after will render after. something like

before : z-index = 0, container: z-index = 1, and after: z-index = 2

but the order is before : z-index = 1, container: z-index = 0, and after: z-index = 2

HTML:

```
<div id=theDiv>DIV</div>
```

CSS:

```
#theDiv{
  position:relative;
  width:100px; height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  margin:50px;
}
#theDiv:before{
  content:"Before";
  position:absolute; top:-30px; left:-30px;
  width:90px; height:90px;
  background-color:blue;
}
#theDiv:after{
  content:"After";
  position:absolute; top:30px; left:30px;
  width:90px; height:90px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shprung/892y1gzc/

My usual solution is to force on the before a z-index of -1 which fill like a hack.

[The specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content) don't mentioned the stacking order by indirectly suggests what I was hoping for :

> ...As their names indicate, the :before and :after pseudo-elements
>   specify the location of content before and after an element's document
>   tree content...

Any better solution than forcing the z-index:-1 ?

Other similar question want to assume that all you need is to setup new stacking content, but this is not the case. for example, if you give each a z-index like the code below it still not behave correctly. so the z-index:-1 for the before is some unique case and this is why I am puzzled.

```
#theDiv{
  z-index:50;
  position:relative;
  width:100px; height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  margin:50px;
}
#theDiv:before{
  z-index:1;
  content:"Before"; 
  position:absolute; top:-30px; left:-30px;
  width:90px; height:90px;
  background-color:blue;
}
#theDiv:after{
  z-index:100;
  content:"After";
  position:absolute; top:30px; left:30px;
  width:90px; height:90px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [z-index of :before or :after to be below the element, Is that possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032856/z-index-of-before-or-after-to-be-below-the-element-is-that-possible)

Comment: It's not a hack, it's how it's designed to work.

Comment: `:before` renders before the _content_ of `#theDiv` not before the actual `div`. But yea, use `-1` for `z-index`, and you can also use `pointer-events: none`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`::before` and `::after` create pseudo elements as *children* of the selected element, not as siblings. So adding a `::before` and `::after` to `#theDiv` is similar to creating:

```
<div id="theDiv">
    <span id="theDiv_before"></span>
    DIV
    <span id="theDiv_after"></span>
</div>
```

Child elements stack above parent elements, and that's why the pseudo elements display that way.

See this article on [the stacking context in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index) for more information.

The solution would be to either create the pseudo elements on the container of your div or else keep using `z-index: -1`.

Comment: This would have been a great answer if it also included the solution!