# CSS transparent down triangle using only after

Tags: html, css

I need to create a page using CSS triangle. My concern is that I can only use `:after`.

Image

[Need CSS for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjm0j.png)

HTML:

```
<div class="logo">
  <!--<div class="down"></div>-->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logo {
  background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-
  flat/24/678110-sign-info-128.png");
  width:124px;
  height: 131px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 290px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 93px;
  z-index: 10 !important;
  position: relative;
  /*margin-right: 160px;*/
}

.logo::after {
  content: '';
  border-left: 80px solid transparent;
  border-right: 80px solid transparent;
  border-top: 80px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 90px;
  left: -15px;
  /*top: 120px;
  left: 275px;*/
  clear: both;
  /*transform-origin: 0 100%;        
  transform: rotate(45deg);*/
  /*margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: 0px;*/
  z-index: 0 !important;
}
```

I want logo should be display above the triangle.

Comment: Your child element can't be below parent.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of a question you posted a couple of days ago, I suggest you update the original question with the new information and delete this one. If you do this I should be able to come up with a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because **z-index** is applied to logo class both the times which is the same class you need to remove z-index from **.logo** and add **-ve z-index** to **.logo::after**.

```
.logo {
background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678110-sign-info-128.png");
width:124px;
height: 131px;
float: left;
margin-left: 290px;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-bottom: 93px;
position: relative;
/*margin-right: 160px;*/
 }
 .logo::after {
content: '';
 border-left: 80px solid transparent;
border-right: 80px solid transparent;
border-top: 80px solid white;
position: absolute;
width: 0;
height: 0;
top: 90px;
left: -15px;
/*top: 120px;
left: 275px;*/
clear: both;
 /*transform-origin: 0 100%;        
transform: rotate(45deg);*/
/*margin-top: 90px;
margin-left: 0px;*/
z-index: -1;
 }
```

Here is a working link : https://jsfiddle.net/qk5u45Lv/

Comment: I was about to post the same.
For more information, you can check this post : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032856/is-it-possible-to-set-the-stacking-order-of-pseudo-elements-below-their-parent-e

Comment: Unfortunately this would place the triangle beneath everything. I've added a container with a background to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/qk5u45Lv/1/

Comment: Then you can add the ``::after`` to the container ?

Comment: @anierzad moreover I found the container background is overshadowing the triangle

Comment: This is really helpful.Thank you.

Comment: Please up vote my question if this is relevant.

Comment: @SiddP it's covering the triangle because you've given it a negative z-index. Every other element on the page will have at least a z-index of 0 and will appear on top of the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

One more alternative:

HTML:

```
<div class="logo"><span>i</span></div>

Apply this css:

.logo {
  background: #3498db none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #2980b9;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
}
.logo > span {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: -moz-fixed;
  font-size: 82px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 3px 1px #000;
}

.logo::after {
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 50px solid #f00;
  bottom: -45px;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

OUPUT:

[image]

For more go this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

Hope this will help you!!!

Let me know if there is any query.