# How exactly does stacking context works in case of pseudo elements?

Tags: css, z-index, pseudo-element

I was following how to build a portfolio tutorial on Traversy Media. I have a div#preview with a p tag inside like this

Here is a link to the codepen - https://codepen.io/sankethbk7777/pen/KKmeaLE

```
<div class='right-column'>
       
            <div id='preview'>
              <h3>What I Do</h3>

              <div id='corner-tl' class='corner'></div>
              <div id='corner-tr' class='corner'></div>

              <p>I am a Banglore based computer scinece gradute, aspiring full stack developer. I am open for jobs, internships and freelancing</p>

              <div id='corner-br' class='corner'></div>
              <div id='corner-bl' class='corner'></div>
            </div>
</div>
```

```
.right-column #preview {
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #17a2b8;
  background-color: var(--previewBg);
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 1em;
  background-color: rgba(251, 249, 243, 0.8);;
}
```

[image]

I want to apply a shadow effect like this

[image]

So tried something like this

```
.right-column #preview {
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #17a2b8;
  background-color: rgba(251, 249, 243, 0.8);

  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 1em;
  background-color: rgba(251, 249, 243, 0.8);;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}


.right-column #preview::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:#f0ead6;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
}
```

But it ended up like this

[image]

Based on my understanding of stacking context

```
.right-column #preview {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

creates a new stacking context for preview

Also

```
.right-column #preview::before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

creates a new stacking context for psuedo element but it still respects the stacking context of parent

This is similar to this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_context_example_2) from MDN.

But i don't quite understand why this is not working. I read the stacking context docs on MDN and i also referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032856/is-it-possible-to-set-the-stacking-order-of-pseudo-elements-below-their-parent-e#:%7E:text=To%20position%20a%20pseudo%2Delement,creates%20the%20new%20stacking%20context.) question on StackOverflow. But for a beginner, i couldn't find any helpful explanation.

The solution given in this [blog](http://www.independent-software.com/set-stacking-order-of-pseudo-elements-below-parent-element.html) actually works but i am more interested in understanding the internal working of this.

The solution basically involves creating a wrapper object around #preview and giving it a z-index: -1 to #preview::before.

In short solution is this

```
<div class='right-column'>
  <div class='preview-wrapper'>
    <div id='preview'>
      <h3>What I Do</h3>

      <div id='corner-tl' class='corner'></div>
      <div id='corner-tr' class='corner'></div>

      <p>{myData.whatIDo}</p>

      <div id='corner-br' class='corner'></div>
      <div id='corner-bl' class='corner'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>;
```

```
.right-column .preview-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.right-column #preview {
    position: relative;
    /* No z-index specified */ 
}

.right-column #preview::before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Here is a link to the solution codepen https://codepen.io/sankethbk7777/pen/MWmXpJY

Please help to understand this.

Thank you.

Comment: pseudo element has no special behavior, they behave the same as any kind of element. Consider them as child element of the element where you specify the ::before or ::after

Comment: Thanks i figured it out.