# Pseudo elements get hidden when parent uses background

Tags: html, css

When I apply a `:before` or `:after` pseudo element, this one gets hidden if the parent element uses a background.

You can notice that on this picture, where the red elements gets hidden behind the yellow background. Unlike its parent, the blue element.

[image]

```css
.parent {
  background: yellow;
}

#element {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 4px solid black;
}

#element::after {
  content: "";
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="element"></div>
</div>
```

Reproduction online:
https://jsfiddle.net/subkrovy/

Any way to go around this?

Comment: Do you want the blue square with the red angle to be above the yellow background?

Comment: The blue element is already above it. It's just its pseudo-element that is not. But  yeah, red should be  above.

Comment: I've added borders to make it more clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to set the stacking order of pseudo-elements below their parent element?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9072467/864233)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could translate the parent in the negative z axis. I'm not sure if that's an option for your overall project but in this context, it works.

```css
.parent {
  background: yellow;
  transform: translateZ(-1px)
}

#element {
  position: relative;
  /* optional */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#element::after {
  content: "";
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  /* create a new stacking context */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  /* to be below the parent element */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="element"></div>
  <div id="yellow"></div>
</div>
```

z-index edition because why not:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
}

#element {
  position: relative;
  /* optional */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#element::after {
  content: "";
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  /* create a new stacking context */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  /* to be below the parent element */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="element"></div>
  <div id="yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting! Why did you use `transform` with `translateZ` instead of `z-index`?
z-index seems to cause issues with inputs, but not translateZ.

Comment: @Alvaro I updated my answer. Looks like you *can* use z-index on the parent if you use position: absolute and a defined width. So I guess pick whichever works best for you

Comment: @Alvaro you don't need a negative z-index on the parent, any z-index will do the job even a positive one

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah I guess it doesn't matter, you could even use 0. Looks like relative position works too

Comment: @TemaniAfif uh wow, that's interesting... why is it? Seems to be working!

Comment: @Alvaro read the duplicate to understand the concept of stacking context