# z-index priority on ul and child

Tags: css, z-index, css-position

Basically I want a relative element to hide its absolute child on the z plan.

```
ul {z-index:10; position:relative;}
ul ul {z-index:-10; position:absolute;}
```

They are positonned on top of each other. 
The first  should hide its child, but it's not happening that way.

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qajp6/2). I try to make the red part disappear under the blue one.

Any help muy appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Remove z-index:999; from #menu

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this way makes me use a negative z-index for my wrapper which I do not want.

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806421/css-parent-element-to-appear-above-child

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific thing you're trying to do can't be done.  By setting a `z-index` on the parent ul, you cause that element to become a new stacking context, which according to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index), means that its background and borders will always sit below all of its child elements.

The effect you want may still be achievable if you remove the `z-index` setting from the parent ul.  This doesn't mean that you have to adjust the rest of the z-indexes in your page to compensate; all you have to do is provide another element to be the context - for instance, the parent element of the parent ul.  To make that element a stacking context, you just have to give it a z-index value - any z-index value, so long as it's a number.