# css stacking order, z-index

Tags: html, css

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the red on top without changing the html structure.

http://jsfiddle.net/GSBtG/

How do I get the red on top?  I've red every combination of z-index values and position, etc.

The HTML:

```
<div id="red">
    <div id="green"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px
}
#red {
    background: red;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
}
#green {
    background: green;
    width: 290px;
    z-index: -10
}
```

Comment: I think you have to change the HTML structure...you could do that with Javascript if changing the original HTML is difficult.

Comment: recommend these articles on z-index: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/  and http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `Z-Index` from the parenting element and give both elements the same `position:` rule.

Proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/GSBtG/2/#update

Comment: It would work. You can disregard the 25. I just do larger steps in case I ever need to place something between two elements.

Comment: Upvoted this answer because it works. But I want just to point out that what happens is that green one is going behind the red one, not the red one in front of the green one which would be imposible to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Set a negative `z-index` on the child and remove the `z-index` on the parent.

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
}
#child {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -10;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GSBtG/1/)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806421/css-parent-element-to-appear-above-child)