# How to reverse the order of nested child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Suppose I have the following HTML Code

**HTML**

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
   <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.a, .b, .c {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.a {
  background: red;
   z-index: 999;
}

.b {
  background: green;
   margin: 40px;
   z-index: 500;
}

.c {
  background: gray;
  margin: 40px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Now, i want it to be exactly opposite i.e, red on top of all.
I tried using z-index with position set to `relative` but it doesn't work. 
Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WT4Bh/) demo

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to have red div on top, green in middle and gray at the bottom using either javascript or jQuery?

Comment: The stacking context resets whenever you nest elements — aka the `z-index` values are only relevant when comparing siblings, not when comparing parent-child nesting. The parent will ALWAYS be behind the children, regardless of the z-index.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806421/css-parent-element-to-appear-above-child

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The parent will always be behind the children, [**as `z-index` values are stacked**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index).

> The order in which the rendering tree is painted onto the canvas is described in terms of stacking contexts. Stacking contexts can contain further stacking contexts. A stacking context is atomic from the point of view of its parent stacking context; boxes in other stacking contexts may not come between any of its boxes. - W3 http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index

By setting a `z-index` on `.a`, you are also setting the same `z-index` on all the children. For instance, by setting `z-index:999` on `.a` -- `.b`, and `.c` now also have the same indexes, rending it useless. To achieve this, the elements cannot be a parent nor a child of another, they would have to be siblings for this to work.

Here is what it would look like if they are siblings - [**it works!**](http://jsfiddle.net/k6dNP/)