# Why won't a child element with a lesser z-index than it's parents show behind the parent?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am trying to figure out why a child element does not appear behind its parent element when given a lower z-index value than the parent.  It only appears to work when you do **not** touch the parent's default z-index value.

Here's a basic example.

HTML:

```
<div class="a">
    A DIV
    <div class="b">
        B DIV
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a {
    position: relative;
    background: #eaeaea;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 20;
}
.b {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -20;
    background: #d6d6d6;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Link to example:
http://jsfiddle.net/V4786/2/

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe because if it is inside the parent it will be on the same z-index as the parent. It needs to not be in the parent to be on its own z-index.

Comment: `z-index` values are stacked... see [How to reverse the order of nested child elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454901/how-to-reverse-the-order-of-nested-child-elements)

Comment: what you are looking for is `stacking context` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It only appears to work when you do **not** touch the parent's default z-index value.

This is because setting `z-index` to something other than its default `auto` on a positioned element causes it to establish a new stacking context, and an element cannot be positioned behind the element that created the stacking context that it's in. (An element cannot be positioned behind the root stacking context, for example, as [Scotty C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920033/why-wont-a-child-element-with-a-lesser-z-index-than-its-parents-show-behind-th/19920099#19920099) states.)

When you leave the `z-index` of the parent element untouched, the parent and the child both participate in the same stacking context, which is the one established by the root element, or the *root stacking context*. This is why you can position the child behind the parent in such a case.

All the details can be found in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers), but that's the gist of it given your question.

Answer (score 1):

Because Z-Index levels are relative to their parents. This is the same as saying "Why doesn't the element show behind the browser window if I set a negative Z-Index?" Generally if you're going to do something funky with levels, you might consider having two sibling elements with absolute or relative positioning. Although that approach is sometimes considered "hacky."