# How to bring parent div front?

Tags: html, css

How to bring parent div front?

My html:-

```
<div class="main">
 <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

My css :-

```
.main{
 width : 400px;
 height: 400px;
 background : green;
 z-index: 10; 
}
.parent{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: relative;
 background: yellow;
 z-index: 5;
} 
.child{
 width : 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: red;
 z-index : -1;
}
```

My js fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/gautm5154/xPvHf/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806421/css-parent-element-to-appear-above-child

Comment: Why would you want to? In this instance you would just swap the parent and child wouldn't you?

Comment: It's not possible, parent element is always under his child(ren). There is no chance to set parent higher z-index then child(ren).

Comment: @panther Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sambomartin's answer is how I would do it but I will just show it is possible to get parent to show above the child element.

**CSS:**

```
.main {
    width : 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border :1px solid black;
}
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #e3e3e3;
    z-index: 1;
}
.child {
    width : 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/xPvHf/6/)

Comment: Check this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gautm5154/xPvHf/8/).Why child is appearing below main?

Comment: @GautamKumar What about it?

Comment: Why child is appearing below main?

Comment: @GautamKumar [Fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/xPvHf/9/) Like I said I wouldn't do it this way. Im just proving it is possible. IT was doing that because the child is set to -1 z-index. So its behind the background.

Comment: main div should have lower zindex then child div to appear?

Comment: @GautamKumar I wouldn't look to much into this as its not really necessary. When you have a better handle on how z-index works come back to this answer and see whats happening. For now stick to the other answer as it is just a better way.

Answer (score 5):

The `parent` can never be in front of an element it contains.

Are you trying to do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/Zc9Ch/

The css would be more like this

```
.main{
        width : 400px;
        height: 400px;
        border :1px solid black;            
        position:relative;
    }
    #bottom{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        background: #e3e3e3;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #top {
        width : 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: red;
        z-index:2;
        position:absolute;
    }
```

HTML for completeness

```
<div class="main">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="bottom""></div>
</div>
```

Obviously in your examplethe `parent` and  `child` css classes don't really make sense, i've changed to ids in the answer.

Comment: @GautamKumar Check my answer out, it is possible but as I said this is how I would do it too.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="parent"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main {
    width : 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background : green;
    z-index: 10;
}
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background: yellow;
    z-index: 5;
}
.child {
    width : 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    z-index : -1;
    margin: -100px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: This is terrible. What

Comment: @Ruddy when you put the background color in the css then your div disapper :P
checkout with this css
.main {
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}
.parent {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 yellow;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.child {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red !important;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: -1;
}

Comment: Throwing code at here isn't good. Should explain a little bit of what you are doing. As your code doesn't make it clear, you also have no demo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.main {
    width : 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border :1px solid black;
}
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #e3e3e3;
    z-index: 1;
}
.child {
    width : 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
}
```

By the way for z-index to work (here in `.main`) You need to set position either to `relative`, `fixed` or `absolute`.

Finally here is a jsfiddle to show you it: http://jsfiddle.net/xPvHf/7/

Comment: So let me see here, what you have done is copied my answer. Very nice!

Comment: Lol I swear I have not mate, there is no infinite ways of making it.

Comment: You should check other answers before posting. No need to create dupes. I'm not going to down-vote as its a good answer but please be aware of other peoples answers next time.

Comment: I'm sorry I was typing mine, I did not see the others poping up :/

Answer (score 0):

I have added opacity to make continuity

.main {

```
width : 400px;
height: 400px;
border :1px solid black;
background-color:#000000;
opacity:.19;
filter: alpha(opacity=19);
-moz-opacity:.19;
z-index:1;
```

}

.parent {

```
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: #000000;
z-index: -1;
```

}

.child {

```
width : 200px;
height: 200px;
background: red;
z-index: -1;
position: relative;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/shivassmca/vpHB9/