# Z-index and transition css property conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my page, I have 3 placeholder images under my portfolio section. What I want is for the images to get wider and taller when they are hovered. However, I also have a fixed header set with a z-index of 1000 (for obvious reasons). The issue is that for some reason, even though I have set my containers to position: relative with a z-index of -1, the images still appear over my header when I scroll down. Here is my codepen snippet:

https://codepen.io/PatrickVegas/full/RVapzR/

```
 * { font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; }* HEADER/HOME ---------------------------------*/
```

What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: For me its behind the navigation. Sorry but I dont really get your problem could you explain it for me once more?

Comment: Working for me. If you are using Chrome, try Ctrl+Refresh to do a hard refresh of the page.

Comment: It's ok for me, only that you have a weird animation on the header after scrolling down: background appear, then all disappears and appears again.

Comment: @KrisJ. i want to add a transition effect to height and width of images when they're hovered, but it's not working when they are positioned.

Answer (score 2):

#### Add the `position: relative;` and `z-index: 9999;` to your css class `container-header` will fix the problem you have with those images.

```
.container-header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
  ...

 }
```

## https://codepen.io/hdl881127/pen/eWzzBp

Most of the time when you can't position something, try to move up to the parent and see what's in there. In your case here `<div class="portfolio" id="portfolio">` are sibling with your nav menu `<div class="container-header" id="home">`, you can't position them if you only add index to their child element.

take a look at this img, it provide tons of information about position:

[image]

I know there are lots of answer in stack-overflow but this link helped me alot when I think about this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: @ChrisHappy oops, I didn't save, try now.

Comment: The problem is that my hovering effects are not working when the z-index is less than that of the header's.

Comment: @user3403337 does this fix the problem now? https://codepen.io/hdl881127/pen/eWzzBp

Comment: @user3403337 take a look at this post I answered, play around with the code sample, might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055941/z-index-not-working-in-my-code/43056069#43056069

Comment: @user3403337 this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/43056069/4739018, the code have two example, which shows z-index and how it works with parent/child or same level element =D. Please accept the answer if that fixed your problem, thanks!