# Z-index not working for ribbon, background and input

Tags: html, css, reactjs, ribbon

I ran into a problem yesterday in my React app, but it is really just HTML:

I'm making an app with a background, and input and a ribbon. Here is the code for my ribbon:

```
const MyRibbon = styled.div`
    background: ${blueLight};
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;

  &:before, &:after {
        content: "";
        width: 50px;
        bottom: -5px;
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        border: 14px solid ${blueDark};
        z-index: -1;  
    }

    &:before {
        left: -40px;
        border-right-width: 12px;
        border-left-color:transparent;
    }

    &:after {
        right: -40px;
        border-left-width: 12px;
        border-right-color:transparent;
    }
`;
```

and this is the code for my background:

```
const Div = styled.div`
    background-color: rgb(242,242,242);
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: -1000;
`;
```

I am expecting this to create a ribbon with the :before and :after els behind the ribbon. However, they come up above it. Somehow, I managed to fix this yesterday eve, which I cannot recreate now. Nevertheless, once I added an input field, it wouldn't be clickable, even when I fiddled with the form's and its `position: relative` and `z-index`.

Can somebody pleease help me?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally got it to work per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10156261/4204961) answer. Instead of setting a `position` and `z-index` on the background `div`, I wrapped only the ribbon (in a `div` with `position: relative` and `z-index: 5`). Then I have `.ribbon {position: relative;}` and `.ribbon:before, .ribbon:after {position: absolute; z-index: -2}`. This is a clever way thanks to which the `input` still works!

Hope that helps somebody.