# how to lower z-index of inner absolute div with respect to outer absolute div?

Tags: html, css

What I want:
[image]

---

What I am getting instead:
[image]

---

Respective code: https://jsfiddle.net/JerryGoyal/2zy2wj78/4/

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 20px blue;
  border-radius: 51%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
}

.line {
  margin: 0 0 0 -2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 6px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class='circle'>
  <div class='line'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you just remove z-index from parent?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806421/how-to-get-a-parent-element-to-appear-above-child

Comment: @NenadVracar no I can't because there are other elements on the page   which would hide this parent div

Comment: Then try that second answer on linked question.

Comment: @NenadVracar hmm that worked https://jsfiddle.net/JerryGoyal/2zy2wj78/15/.. but could it be possible without adding any wrapper?